# OSX Shell replace string in a file error with character

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I know I'm probably missing something obvious but haven't been able to figure out exactly what my issue is.  I'm trying to replace all instances of a line in a file that starts with a certain string as seen below:

```
sed -i '' 's/.*<CodesignProvision>.*/<CodesignProvision>22-22-22</CodesignProvision>/' $WORKSPACE/file/file1
```

This is giving me the error:

> ```
> sed: 1: "s/.*<CodesignProvision> ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'C'
> ```

Is it the `<` that is causing the issue and what can I do about it?  I've used sed before but not too extensively, haven't run into this yet.

Thanks

Comment: `sed -i '' 's~.*<CodesignProvision>.*~<CodesignProvision>22-22-22</CodesignProvision>~' $WORKSPACE/file/file1` Use alternative delimiter

Comment: Wow that was dense of me.  It's because of the / in the end tag isn't it.... Thank you!